# Ignore SQL where clause on null cases

Tags: sql, select, plsql, where-clause

I'm trying to make a select from a table, my problem is that some of the columns in this table, which are foreign keys, can be null.

2 of these foreign keys are exclusive, if one of them has data, the other one will be null, and vice versa. So when I try to write the `where` clause so that one of them will always be null and I can't retrieve any data.

Example:

```
Select 
    t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.pk1, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.pk2, t3.col5, t3.pk3
from 
    t1, t2, t3
where 
    t2.pk2 = t1.pk2
    and t3.pk3 = t1.pk3
```

One of those clauses will always be false, because one of the columns will always be null on the table1. My ideal solution would be to make the specific where clause be ignored in the case that the value on table 1 is null, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx) instead:

```
Select    t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.pk1, 
          t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.pk2, 
          t3.col5, t3.pk3
From      t1
Left Join t2 On t2.pk2 = t1.pk2
Left Join t3 On t3.pk3 = t1.pk3
```

By using an `INNER JOIN`, you're filtering the records that don't satisfy all of the `JOIN` conditions.  An `OUTER JOIN` will return a `NULL` value for the outer table (in the case of a `LEFT JOIN`, the right-hand table) where the `JOIN` condition is not satisfied.

As a side note, you should *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  This old implicit `JOIN` syntax was deprecated [*over 25 years ago!*](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really well explained.